# Error: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: next.js, serverless, vercel

So I created a **[Serverless API](https://github.com/jareer12/graphs)** with Next.js and hosted it on vercel but I'm facing an error saying:

```yaml
2021-08-24T12:45:22.228Z    undefined   ERROR   Error: libuuid.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1131:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
RequestId: 0b859497-64b4-4adb-8fe1-8b172459cc6b Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

[image]

Is it because I use canvas module or because i use `require()`?

Comment: I met the same issue with node10 canvas 2.8.0, tried with 2.5.0 but not work

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1893#issuecomment-983708418